# Parse an HTML Table returned from an ASP page using AJAX and Extract Specific Cells

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

There is an ASP page on work intranet that returns data from numerous sensors. The data is presented in table format with several rows and columns.

I thought it would be cool if I could display a few of the outputs on our department website.

I would like to use ajax to open the ASP page and get a few data points from the resulting table.

Opening up the page with AJAX was easy enough, but I'm not sure what to do with it after that.

The table is formatted like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Data ID 1</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data ID 2</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first cell in each row is a unique ID, then the 5th column in the same row has the value I want.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://plantdata/showData.asp",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How can I grab the data by the unique ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var target = document.getElementById("testDiv");
    target.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    extractIDs(target);
  }
}

function extractIDs(container) {
  var trs = container.getElementsByTagName("TR");

  for (var i=0; i<trs.length; i++) {
    var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("TD"),
        txt = tds[0].textContent || tds[0].innerText;  // innerText for IE

    alert("row " + (i+1) + ": " + txt);
  } 
};
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it I want to avoid actually displaying the entire table on the main page. I only want to display certain rows. I need to retrieve the document, and search it without displaying it first.

Comment: @SharpBarb Well, load it into a container with `display: none;`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for jQuery for sure. Can I see the output and then I will show you the answer, but it is along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "TableData.html",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                var tempData = $(data);
                //alert(tempData.html());

                tempData.find("tr td[id]").each(function (i) {
                    alert($(this).siblings(":nth-child(5n)").text());
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I was kinda hoping for a solution that doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: @SharpBarb - Why? Let it do the heavy lifting.

Comment: What's wrong with it? It's a cross-browser toolbox to ease your development. It's not that heavy. It produces simple code (see Sam answer).

Comment: @SharpBarb - If you want to use jQuery, I have edited my post to do what you need.

Comment: @Zopieux I'm all for jQuery, but the problem with it is that people should also know how to achieve things without it.

Comment: @entonio - Why? It is there to abstract away the headaches most people will get from JavaScript. I can't believe we are still stuck with JavaScript for the only real client-side language to use. It is cool and all, and jQuery makes it WAY better, but I mean Really??

Comment: @Sam if people are getting headaches from javascript they have to solve their headaches first. It's one thing to abstract away browser idiosyncrasies, quite another to obscure the language. jQuery is javascript and if you don't know javascript then you don't really know jQuery, and you end up writing it the wrong way.

Comment: @entonio - I can agree with that, but then I would have to say that jQuery abstracts the heavy lifting away for you. That is priceless!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the table's rows:

```
var data;
var rows=document.getElementById("testDiv").getElementsByTagName('table')[0].rows;
for(var i=0; i<rows.length; ++i)
{
    var cells=rows[i].cells;
    if(cells[0].innerHTML == uniqueID)
    {
        data=cells[4].innerHTML;
        break;
    }
}
```